# generating a new set of random number after alert

Tags: jquery, math, sum

I have a table as below.

```
<tr>
<td><div id="1">1</div></td>
<td><div id="2">2</div></td>
<tr>
```

When the document is fully loaded, the number is being randomize first in the range of 1-5, and replacing the table cell with the new random number. Then they are being add together.

```
var num1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
var num2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);

$("#1").replaceWith(num1);
$("#2").replaceWith(num2);

var sum = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
```

User will key in the answer in the text area. Button on click check the answer with sum of the 2 randomized number.

```
    $(":button").click(function () {
    var text = $(":text").val();
    if(text == sum)
    {
        alert("you answer correctly");

    }
    else
    {
        alert("you answer wrongly");
    }

});
```

My question is, after the user dismissed the alert, how can a new set of randomized number be generated? Like using a loop or something?

Comment: I didn't understand your Q correctly, what do u mean by dismissed the alert?

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the random generation code after displaying the alert()

```
var sum;

function random() {
    var num1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
    var num2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);

    $("#1").html(num1);
    $("#2").html(num2);

    sum = num1 + num2;
}

random();

$(":button").click(function () {
    var text = $(":text").val();
    if (text == sum) {
        alert("you answer correctly");
    } else {
        alert("you answer wrongly");
    }
    random();
});
```

```js
var sum;

function random() {
  var num1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
  var num2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);

  $("#1").html(num1);
  $("#2").html(num2);

  sum = num1 + num2;
}

random();

$(":button").click(function() {
  var text = $(":text").val();
  if (text == sum) {
    alert("you answer correctly");
  } else {
    alert("you answer wrongly");
  }
  random();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="1">1</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="2">2</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input />
<button>Test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a function and call it after alert.
please refer the code  http://jsbin.com/nevoregiho/7/edit

```
var num1 = 0;
var num2 = 0;
var sum = 0;

function randomNumber(){
num1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
num2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
$("#one").text(num1);
$("#two").text(num2);
sum =  parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
}

randomNumber();

   $("button").click(function () {
    var text = $("#result").val();
    if(text == sum)
    {
      alert("you answer correctly");
      randomNumber();
      $("#result").val("");

    }
    else
    {
        alert("you answer wrongly");
    }

});
```